# rngd - multiple instances from init script

Tags: daemon, random, start-stop-daemon

On Ubuntu >=12.04, what is the most correct/prettiest way to get rngd to run in multiple instances using an init script? The current one only accepts one random source, so multiple instances are needed.

I.e. I would like `rngd` to be controlled with the "service" command.

When I manually start `rngd`, it works as I hoped and thus gathering randomness twice the speed of just a single source.

```
$ rngd --pidfile=/var/run/rngd0.pid -r /dev/hwrng0  
$ rngd --pidfile=/var/run/rngd1.pid -r /dev/hwrng1
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

### Edit

End version looks like this, thanks [@CameronNemo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/55528/cameronnemo):
/etc/init/rng-tools.conf:

```
description     "rng-tools daemon"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

env DEVLIST="$(find /dev/hwrng* -follow -type c)"

pre-start script
  for device in $DEVLIST; do
    start rngd-instance DEVICE=$device || failed="${failed}$device "
  done
  test -n "$failed" || { echo "Failed to start instances: $failed"; exit 1; }
end script
```

/etc/init/rngd-instance.conf:

```
stop on stopping rng-tools or runlevel [016]

description "rngd instance"
usage "DEVICE=full path to rng device"

instance $DEVICE

pre-start script
  test -c "$DEVICE" || { echo "Not a device: $DEVICE"; exit 1; }
  mkdir -p /var/run/rngd
end script

exec rngd --foreground --pidfile=/var/run/rngd/$(basename "$DEVICE") -r $DEVICE
```

/etc/init.d/rng-tools :

```
$ cd /etc/init.d/
$ sudo ln -sf /lib/init/upstart-job rng-tools
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to write an Upstart job using instances (the device file would be the instance), then another job that starts all the instances you want at boot.

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#instance

It would be easier for you if you made the pidfiles based on the device name, so it would be something like "rngd-instance":

```
stop on stopping rng-tools or runlevel [016]

instance $DEVICE
usage "DEVICE=full path to rng device"

pre-start script
    test -c $DEVICE || { echo "Not a device: $DEVICE"; exit 1; }
    mkdir -p $(dirname /var/run/rngd/$DEVICE)
end script

exec rngd --foreground --pidfile=/var/run/rngd/$DEVICE -r $DEVICE
```

then another job, rng-tools, like this:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

env DEVLIST="/dev/hwrng0 /dev/hwrng1"

pre-start script
    for d in $DEVLIST; do
        initctl start rngd-instance DEVICE=$d || failed="${failed}$d "
    done
    test -n "$failed" || { echo "Failed to start instances: $failed"; exit 1; }
end script
```

You place these files as /etc/init/rngd-instance.conf and /etc/init/rng-tools.conf.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the pointers. It works perfectly now! On a side note, I also learned about an upstart bug and a workaround for it: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=582745